# How can i solve these Errors while consuming JMS in wso2esb

Tags: jms, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

> I am using wso2esb4.7.0 and ActiveMQ5.8.0
>   http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/ESB+as+a+JMS+Producer and
>   http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/ESB+as+a+JMS+Consumer according to
>   the document i have done and  my messages are passing well to
>   queue.Even storing also well .
>
> While consuming the messages in to the queue Wso2esb giving issues
>   like formats ERROR - JMSMessageReceiver Unknown error processing
>   message org.apache.axiom.om.OMException:
>   com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '{'
>   (code 123) in prolog; expected '<' at [row,col {unknown-source}]:
>   [1,1]

```
why this happening is there any message format issue i am passing just
sample json like
And here is my curl command
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H
"Content-Type:application/json" -H "ModifiedOn:0" -H
"username:vikaash|21405735755158656" -H "password:gbin" -d
'{"name":"youtility tech","mail":"faisal.shaik@youtility.in"}'
http://youtility2-desktop:8282/services/JmsStore
```

Comment: What i can infer is that, `{` should be removed somewhere and `<` should be added somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please remove your format and content type parameters in your code then you will get proper message